# Dropdown within card that is a fully clickable and opens a modal

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog, dropdown

I'm having issues with getting my dropdown to work when it's inside a fully clickable card.

Basically what's happening is that I can't click the three dots with the dropdown without it opening the modal. I'm not sure how to separate the two.

I still want the card to be fully clickable but also have the dropdown when I click on the three dots.

### My code

```
<div class="card card-container">
        <div class="card-body">
            <img class="mr-4" src="images/icon.png" width="30px" height="30px" >
            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#viewContact" style="color: inherit; "class="stretched-link">Contact_name</a>
            <span class="d-inline float-right">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" id="imageDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <img src="images/ellipsis.png" width="30px" height="30px">
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="imageDropdown">
                        <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editContact" role="presentation"><a class="ml-3" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Edit</a></li>
                        <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteContact" role="presentation"><a class="ml-3" style="color: red;" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Delete</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </span> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

Fully clickable card:
[image: fully clickable card]

Modal being displayed:
[image: modal that comes up from it]

Dropdown on the card:
[image: the dropdown on the card]

Comment: Can you provide a link to all of your code?

Comment: https://github.com/Kimcheemo/contactManager/tree/homePage

Answer (score 0):

I review your code, the problem is that if the card is completely clickable you need to set a style property that indicates that a specific element is on top of the clickable card, in this case `z-index` property will do the job.

**Try the following code:**

> I added `z-index:99` to the dropdown `<span>` element.

```
<div class="card card-container">
    <div class="card-body">
        <img class="mr-4" src="images/icon.png" width="30px" height="30px" />
        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#viewContact" style="color: inherit; "class="stretched-link">Contact_name</a>
        
        <!-- Dropdown element -->
        <span class="d-inline float-right" style="z-index:99">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" id="imageDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <img src="images/ellipsis.png" width="30px" height="30px">
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="imageDropdown">
                    <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editContact" role="presentation"><a class="ml-3" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Edit</a></li>
                    <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteContact" role="presentation"><a class="ml-3" style="color: red;" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Delete</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </span> 
        <!-- End of dropdown element -->

    </div>
</div>
```

**Definition and Usage:** the z-index property specifies the stack order of an element. An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.